# Is it possible for pine script to place an order based on a trigger, then exit that order an exact number of bars away?

Tags: pine-script

So I am trying to see if Pine script within tradingview is able to execute a trade then exit that trade an exact number of bars away from that entry point. Just curious if possible

Answer (score 1):

Test on `barssince(change(strategy.position_size)) >= 10` for 10 bars.